# Is there any possibility that QAbstractItemModel::beginResetModel and endResetModel can create a performance issue?

Tags: qml, qt5, qabstractlistmodel

My Dev setup:
Qt version : Qt 5.15.0
OS: Embedded Linux

I have a list of information.
Assume I have a structure called **MyStruct** 
My model class is having a member variable of **QList** of above structure, to hold data for my view. Whenever I am opening the view, I am updating the QList (Note: There may or may not be a change). Updating here is something like assigning a new QList to existing one. before assignment, I am calling **beginResetModel** and after assignment I am calling **endResetModel**,

```
void MyModelClass::SomeInsertMethod(const QList<MyStruct>& aNewData)
{
    beginResetModel();
    m_lstData = aNewData;
    endResetModel();
}
```

One thing I believe can be improved, is putting a check, if the new data is different than the existing data and then doing the above. Something like this:

```
void MyModelClass::SomeInsertMethod(const QList<MyStruct>& aNewData)
{
    if  (m_lstData != aNewData)
    {
        beginResetModel();
        m_lstData = aNewData;
        endResetModel();
    }
}
```

Apart from that, is there any possibilities of getting a performance issue for calling beginResetModel/endResetModel? I m seeing a very small delay in the view coming up in my application.
I checked the documentation of **QAbstractItemModel** for above methods. Didn't get anything specific to the performance issue.
The other way, which this can be done, is by individually comparing the elements of the lists and triggering a **dataChanged** signal with appropriate model index and roles. But I feel, this will unnecessarily introduce some additional loops and comparisons, which again may cause some other performance issue. Correct me if I am wrong. 
Is there any advantage of using **dataChanged** over **beginResetModel/EndResetModel**?
Please let me know your views on the above.

Comment: In my application I am using Qt6 and I can see that 'QAbstractItemModel::endResetModel()' is hanging few seconds every now and than...